# Difficulty in creating Core Data managed objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

At the moment I can't see any `AUser` objects in my sqlite3 app database.

This is the code I have to create a user. Am I missing something? There are no warnings/errors with the code.

```
AUser *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AUser" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];  // _managedObjectContext is declared elsewhere

user.name = username;  //username is some string declared elsewhere / name is an attribute of AUser
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform a save on the context.

```
NSError* error = nil;
if(![context save:&error]) {        
    // something went wrong
    NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

When you perform a save, data in the context are saved to the persistent store coordinator (hence in your sql store).

P.S. Based on the discussion with **@G. Shearer**, in production if the context fails to save, you can handle the error gracefully. This means not using `abort()` call that causes the app to crash.

```
NSError* error = nil;
if(![context save:&error]) {        
    // save failed, perform an action like alerting the user, etc.
} else {
    // save success
}
```

Comment: Oh ok! Somehow I must have skipped the saving part while reading through the CoreData docs lol. Thanks!

Comment: You don't necessarily want that abort() call in there.  it IS possible to have a Core Data error that is not your applications fault.  If possible to gracefully maintain application state, you should.  A call to abort() in production code will simply make your application crash, which will make users angry.

Comment: @G.Shearer You're right. But in my opinion, production errors like this should not happen. If they happen, users will not be happy. Yes, a different way to handle the error is possible but this is is only an example. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @G.Shearer Based on my experience, such type of errors are due to bugs caused by the developer. But maybe I'm wrong... ;-)

Comment: @flexaddicted, you might be right about MOST of those errors being cause by a developer.  But killing an application when you catch an error (in production) is equally as callous as writing the bug in the first place.  SOFTWARE IS NEVER PERFECT. I AM NOT PERFECT. NO ONE IS PERFECT. We all write buggy software, thats why Test-Driven Development started.  But tests can't catch everything, and it's your job as a good developer to write software that handles errors (especially ones you caught like above) __gracefully__.

Comment: @G.Shearer You are perfectly right on this. I don't want to criticize your comment. I mean that this is my preferred way to handle error introduced in my code. I'll edit my answer to fit this discussion. Thanks.

Comment: @flexaddicted also (and this is definitely __not__ meant to come off sarcastic), _In My Personal Experience_, which involves building to-order software to high-powered clients, on unrealistic time-tables.  They would much rather see an Alert popup that tells them that an error occured and their developer has been notified.  A crash really will make them mad.

Comment: thanks @flexaddicted, no criticism taken, always glad to have _debate conversation_ with reasonable people :)

Comment: @G.Shearer I've just edited my answer to insert the discussion we had. Thanks. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call save after creating the object.
Example:

```
NSError *error;
if ([user.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    //Success!
} else {
    //Failure. Check error.
}
```

Comment: Oh ok! Somehow I must have skipped the saving part while reading through the CoreData docs lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to call

```
NSError *error = nil;
[_managedObjectContext save:&error];
if(error != nil) NSLog(@"core data error: %@",[[error userInfo] description]);
```

before the object will be persisted to the database

Comment: Oh ok! Somehow I must have skipped the saving part while reading through the CoreData docs lol. Thanks!